# Text strings must be rendered within Text React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a problem with my `<SearchBar>` and I really don't know where the error is.

This is my **SearchBar**

```
SearchBar({onChange, value, onDelete}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.searchBar}>
        <AntDesign name="search1" size={20} />
        <TextInput onChangeText={onChange} value={value} />
      </View>
      /* wrong */ {value && <AntDesign name="closecircle" size={20} onPress={onDelete} />}
      /* fix*/ {!!value && <AntDesign name="closecircle" size={20} onPress={onDelete} />}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I call it in **Parent**

```
const onSearch = value => {
  setTextSearch(value);

  let filtered = people.filter(function (person) {
    return removeVietnameseTones(person.fullName)
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(removeVietnameseTones(value).toLowerCase());
  });

  setFilteredPeople(filtered);
};

<SearchBar
  onChange={value => onSearch(value)}
  onDelete={() => {
    setTextSearch();
    setFilteredPeople(people);
  }}
  value={textSearch}
/>
```

Everything is working, but when I delete the last letter of **textSearch**, my App will have string bug. They say that:

> Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component

That's all.

Tks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is causing the problem

```
  value && <AntDesign name="closecircle" size={20} onPress={onDelete} />
```

So when value is empty string then react native consider it as a false value and not render next statement, but same time it return value

So react native try to render value (means '' or empty string) and string must be rendered inside Text block

Convert your value to boolean as

```
!!value && <AntDesign name="closecircle" size={20} onPress={onDelete} />
```

or

```
Boolean(value) && <AntDesign name="closecircle" size={20} onPress={onDelete} />
```

Comment: Oh tks. I got it.